# SVM are giving Weird Results on Chest X Rays

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on a Machine Learning Project for identifying Covid 19 from Chest X Rays . I use this data set from kaggle
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/prashant268/chest-xray-covid19-pneumonia
Basically , the problem is that the results and accuracy are about 98% which is a little Weird, i know that SVMs are powerful but not like that.

This Code in Python :

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report , confusion_matrix
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import os
import cv2

categories = ['Covid' , 'Normal']
dir= "This is Path to my folder containinng 2 folder (Covid,Normal) "
label= 0 
data=[]
for category in categories:
   path= os.path.join(dir,category)
   label= categories.index(category)  
   for img in os.listdir(path):
     imgpath=os.path.join(path,img)
     imgstate= cv2.imread(imgpath,0)
     try :
       resizedimage=cv2.resize(imgstate,(220,220))
       #Tranform to Np Array
       resizedimage=np.array(resizedimage).flatten()
       data.append([resizedimage,label])
     except Exception as e:
      pass



random.shuffle(data)

features= []
labels=[]
for feature , label in data :
  features.append(feature)
  labels.append(label) 


X_train , X_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(features,labels, test_size=0.2)
model = SVC(C=1,kernel='poly',gamma ='auto' )
model.fit(X_train , y_train)


predictions = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy' ,accuracy)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

The Number used is about 1000 for Covid Chest X Rays ,and 1000 Normal Chest X Rays.

I have even tried to take Covid 19 and Normal Chest X rays from different X rays , but ended up with very high accuracy!

Comment: So... what is the issue? That your model is too efficient?

Comment: Yes , i know the question itself is weird ! , but Even my supervisor thinks it is a little bit strange .  SVM should be about 70% accurate . thats why we try to implement CNN and Deep Learning algorithms to try to enhance the accuracy to more than 90%